# How to download email address who reffered inside webpage with wget?

Tags: wget

How to download email address who is reffered inside webpage from a website?

I need to scan all pages from this website - parent, children and so on. The goal is to take different e-mail addresses who reffered inside differend pages of the website.

The website has also a robots.txt file, too.

Comment: If this is a email web interface, use an IMAP or POP client instead.

Comment: Do you want to download the whole tree of pages from this site and parse the pages for e-mail addresses? Do you want to build a spam spider?

Answer (score 2):

It is not so simple as you want.

You likely want to download an email with `wget` from a webmail interface. This interface uses a lot of complex things what the browsers can do, but the wget can't (or only through extreme scripting).

However, most webmails have also MAP or POP support, with them you can do it relative easily.

If they don't, then it is still more easy to solve the same task with a different HTTP automatization tool as the `wget`. For example, with [Selenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)) you can automatize real browsers, although it is relative complex to configure, and it eats much more resources. In essence, you need to program it.

In your case I would suggest to go into the direction of POP3/IMAP.